# Linux and bash - How can I get the device name of an input device event?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to automate the process of getting a game controller's device event and checking its name, then if the name matches a string, pass the event to another program.

By hand, I run `evtest /dev/input/eventXX` to check the name of the input device, then keyboard interrupt(ctrl-c) to stop it. If that device matches the name of a certain type of game controller, I run the command `xboxdrv --evtest /dev/input/eventXX` with the same event number.

However, because the "evtest" command continues to print the input device's outputs instead of terminating after printing the name and only exits on keyboard interrupt, I'm not sure how I could have the bash script get the name of the device.

I'm still learning bash so there may be syntax errors in my code. But, here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
WiiUGCName="Wii U Gamecube Adapter Port"

#find the controller(s)
NumberOfEvents=$(ls /dev/input | grep -c event*)

echo "Number of input devices: $NumberOfEvents"

#launch xboxdrv for each controller
i=0
while [ $i < $NumberOfEvents ]; do
    echo "loop"
    OccurrencesOfName=$(evtest /dev/input/event$i | grep -c "$WiiUGCName")
    echo "Occurrences: $OccurrencesOfName"
    if [ $OccurrencesOfName>0 ]; then
        echo "Controller found"
        #launch xboxdrv here
    else
        echo "no controller found"
    fi
    let i=i+1
done
```

All this code actually does right now is hang at that `evtest` since it cannot be terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to give `evtest` some reasonable time to print the interesting portion of the output, say 1 second, and then kill it. If you place that code in a shell function, the resulting code can remain readable. For example, replace:

```
OccurrencesOfName=$(evtest /dev/input/event$i | grep -c "$WiiUGCName")
```

with the invocation of a shell function:

```
OccurrencesOfName=$(evtest_and_exit | grep -c "$WiiUGCName")
```

`evtest_and_exit` can be defined as follows:

```
evtest_and_exit() {
    local evtest_pid
    evtest /dev/input/event$i &
    evtest_pid=$!
    sleep 1  # give evtest time to produce output
    kill $evtest_pid
}
```

Comment: There is no clean way to do that without using evtest, for instance reading some stuff in `/proc/`? How does evtest proceed to get the name of the device?

Comment: @tobiasBora You should probably post that as a separate question.

Comment: @tobiasBora here's a cleaner solution if you're okay with using python:

python -c "from glob import glob; from evdev import InputDevice; print('\n'.join([f'{x} {InputDevice(x).name}' for x in glob('/dev/input/event*')]))"